# kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead

Tags: kubernetes

I wan to create service account with token in Kubernetes. I tried this:

Full log:

```
root@vmi1026661:~# ^C
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl create sa cicd
serviceaccount/cicd created
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                     SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd      0         5s
serviceaccount/default   0         16d

NAME                                 TYPE                 DATA   AGE
secret/repo-docker-registry-secret   Opaque               3      16d
secret/sh.helm.release.v1.repo.v1    helm.sh/release.v1   1      16d
root@vmi1026661:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: cicd
spec:
  serviceAccount: cicd
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: cicd
EOF
pod/cicd created
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("cicd")
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("cicd")
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl create token cicd
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlUyQzNBcmx3RFhBeGdWRjlibEtfZkRPMC12Z0RpU1BHYjFLaWN3akViVVUifQ.eyJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9rdWJlcm5ldGVzLmRlZmF1bHQuc3ZjLmNsdXN0ZXIubG9jY                                                   WwiXSwiZXhwIjoxNjY2NzkyNTIxLCJpYXQiOjE2NjY3ODg5MjEsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8va3ViZXJuZ                                                   XRlcy5kZWZhdWx0LnN2Yy5jbHVzdGVyLmxvY2FsIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pbyI6eyJuYW1lc3BhY2UiO                                                   iJkZWZhdWx0Iiwic2VydmljZWFjY291bnQiOnsibmFtZSI6ImNpY2QiLCJ1aWQiOiI3ODhmNzUwMS0xZ                                                   WFjLTQ0YzktOWQ3Ni03ZjVlN2FlM2Q4NzIifX0sIm5iZiI6MTY2Njc4ODkyMSwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtO                                                   nNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50OmRlZmF1bHQ6Y2ljZCJ9.iBkpVDQ_w_UZmbr3PnpouwtQlLz9FzJs_cJ7IYbY                                                   WUphBM4NO4o8gPgBfnHGPG3uFVbEDbgdY2TsuxHKss0FosiCdjYBiLn8dp_SQd1Rdk0TMYGCLAOWRgZE                                                   XjpmXMLBcHtC5TexJY-bIpvw7Ni4Xls5XPbGpfqL_fcPuUQR3Gurkmk7gPSly77jRKSaF-kzj0oq78MPtwHu92g5hnIZs7ZLaMLzo9EvDRT092RVZXiVF0FkmflnUPNiyKxainrfvWTiTAlYSZreX6JfGjimklTAKCue4w9CqWZGNyGGumqH02ucMQ
xjAiHS6J_Goxyaho8QEvFsEhkVqNFndzbw
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl create token cicd --duration=999999h
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlUyQzNBcmx3RFhBeGdWRjlibEtfZkRPMC12Z0RpU1BHYjFLaWN3akViVVUifQ.eyJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9rdWJlcm5ldGVzLmRlZmF1bHQuc3ZjLmNsdXN0ZXIubG9jY                                                   WwiXSwiZXhwIjo1MjY2Nzg1MzI2LCJpYXQiOjE2NjY3ODg5MjYsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8va3ViZXJuZ                                                   XRlcy5kZWZhdWx0LnN2Yy5jbHVzdGVyLmxvY2FsIiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pbyI6eyJuYW1lc3BhY2UiO                                                   iJkZWZhdWx0Iiwic2VydmljZWFjY291bnQiOnsibmFtZSI6ImNpY2QiLCJ1aWQiOiI3ODhmNzUwMS0xZ                                                   WFjLTQ0YzktOWQ3Ni03ZjVlN2FlM2Q4NzIifX0sIm5iZiI6MTY2Njc4ODkyNiwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtO                                                   nNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50OmRlZmF1bHQ6Y2ljZCJ9.N1V7i0AgW3DihJDWcGbM0kDvFH_nWodPlqZjLSHM                                                   KvaRAfmujOxSk084mrmjkZwIzWGanA6pkTQHiBIAGh8UhR7ijo4J6S58I-5Dj4gu2UWVOpaBzDBrKqBD                                                   SapFw9PjKpZYCHjsXTCzx6Df8q-bAEk_lpc0CsfpbXQl2jpJm3TTtQp1GKuIc53k5VKz9ON8MXcHY8lEfNs78ew8GiaoX6M4_5LmjSNVMHtyRy-Z_oIH9yK8LcHLxh0wqMS7RyW9UKN_9-qH1h01NwrFFOQWpbstFVuQKAnI-RyNEZDc9FZMNwYd_n
MwaKv54oNLx4TniOSOWxS7ZcEyP5b7U8mgBw
root@vmi1026661:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: cicd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "cicd"
EOF
secret/cicd created
root@vmi1026661:~# cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: ClusterRoleBind
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cicd
  namespace: default
EOF
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/ClusterRoleBind created
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                     SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd      0         60s
serviceaccount/default   0         16d

NAME                                 TYPE                                  DATA                                                      AGE
secret/cicd                          kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3                                                         12s
secret/repo-docker-registry-secret   Opaque                                3                                                         16d
secret/sh.helm.release.v1.repo.v1    helm.sh/release.v1                    1                                                         16d
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl describe secret cicd
Name:         cicd
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: cicd
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 788f7501-1eac-44c9-9d76-7f5e7ae3d872

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1099 bytes
namespace:  7 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlUyQzNBcmx3RFhBeGdWRjlibEtfZkRPMC12Z0RpU1BHYjFLaWN3akViVVUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZ                                                   XRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZ                                                   XJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImNpY2QiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2Nvd                                                   W50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoiY2ljZCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291b                                                   nQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LnVpZCI6Ijc4OGY3NTAxLTFlYWMtNDRjOS05ZDc2LTdmNWU3YWUzZDg3M                                                   iIsInN1YiI6InN5c3RlbTpzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudDpkZWZhdWx0OmNpY2QifQ.Uqpr96YyYgdCHQ-GLP                                                   lDMYgF_kzO7LV5B92voDjIPlXa_IQxAL9BdQyFAQmSRS71tLxbm9dvQt8h6mCsfPE_-ixgcpStuNcPtw                                                   GLAvVqrALVW5Qb9e2o1oraMq2w9s1mNSF-J4UaaKvaWJY_2X7pYgSdiiWp7AZg6ygMsJEjVWg2-dLroM-lp1VDMZB_lJPjZ90-lkbsnxh7f_zUeI8GqSBXcomootRmDOZyCywFAeBeWqkLTb149VNPJpYege4nH7A1ASWg-_rCfxvrq_92V2vGFBSvQ
T6-uzl_pOLZ452rZmCsd5fkOY17sbXXCOcesnQEQdRlw4-GENDcv7IA
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl describe sa cicd
Name:                cicd
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   <none>
Tokens:              cicd
Events:              <none>
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl get sa cicd -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-26T12:54:45Z"
  name: cicd
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2206462"
  uid: 788f7501-1eac-44c9-9d76-7f5e7ae3d872
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl get sa,secret
NAME                     SECRETS   AGE
serviceaccount/cicd      0         82s
serviceaccount/default   0         16d

NAME                                 TYPE                                  DATA                                                      AGE
secret/cicd                          kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3                                                         34s
secret/repo-docker-registry-secret   Opaque                                3                                                         16d
secret/sh.helm.release.v1.repo.v1    helm.sh/release.v1                    1                                                         16d
root@vmi1026661:~# ^C
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl describe secret cicd
Name:         cicd
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: cicd
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 788f7501-1eac-44c9-9d76-7f5e7ae3d872

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1099 bytes
namespace:  7 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlUyQzNBcmx3RFhBeGdWRjlibEtfZkRPMC12Z0RpU1BHYjFLaWN3akViVVUifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW5
0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImNpY2QiLCJrdWJlc
m5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC5uYW1lIjoiY2ljZCIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50LnVpZCI6Ijc4OG
Y3NTAxLTFlYWMtNDRjOS05ZDc2LTdmNWU3YWUzZDg3MiIsInN1YiI6InN5c3RlbTpzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudDpkZWZhdWx0OmNpY2QifQ.Uqpr96YyYgdCHQ-GLPlDMYgF_kzO7LV5-02voDjIP
lXa_IQxAL9BdQyFAQmSRS71tLxbm9dvQt8h6mCsfPE_-ixgcpStuNcPtwGLAvVqrALVW5Qb9e2o1oraMq2w9s1mNSF-J4UaaKvaWJY_2X7pYgSdiiWp7AZg6ygMsJEjVWg2-dLroM-lp1VDMZ
B_lJPjZ9DtBblkbsnxh7f_zUeI8GqSBXcomootRmDOZyCywFAeBeWqkLTb149VNPJpYege4nH7A1ASWg-_rCfxvrq_92V2vGFBSvQT6-uzl_pOLZ452rZmCsd5fkOY17sbXXCOcesnQEQdRlw4-GENDcv7IA
root@vmi1026661:~#
root@vmi1026661:~#
```

As you can see I get error:

```
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
    kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
    error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("cicd")
    root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl exec cicd cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
    kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
    error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("cicd")
    root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl create token cicd
```

Do you kno0w what should be the appropriate command to complete this step?

EDIT: here is the result from troubleshooting

```
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cicd                                    1/1     Running   0          67m
repo-docker-registry-78d6c5bdb5-r68jb   0/1     Pending   0          16d
root@vmi1026661:~# kubectl describe pod cicd
Name:             cicd
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  cicd
Node:             vmi1026660/38.242.240.39
Start Time:       Wed, 26 Oct 2022 14:54:57 +0200
Labels:           <none>
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.1.13
IPs:
  IP:  10.244.1.13
Containers:
  cicd:
    Container ID:   containerd://ab44fc463f97316ba807efce0c82e276cf06326e1d03846c1f6186484ff9fcbb
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:47a8d86548c232e44625d813b45fd92e81d07c639092cd1f9a49d98e1fb5f737
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 26 Oct 2022 14:55:22 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-xggpn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-xggpn:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
root@vmi1026661:~#
```

Comment: Check if the pods has crashed out `kubectl get pods` or `kubectl describe pod cicd`. -- `container not found` will come up if the pod is not running, or has crashed

Comment: I added output from the commands.

Comment: Also, the sytnax should should be `kubectl exec -it cicd -- cat ....`

Comment: The error is this "container not found ("cicd")", the deprecated thing is just a warning.

Comment: @BlenderFox you mean `kubectl exec -it cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo` ?

Comment: That should work, yes, but if you're going to use `&&` be careful that your own shell doesn't capture the && and interpret that as `kubectl exec -it cicd -- cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` followed by `echo`. In that case I would recommend using the shell within the pod like this: `kubectl exec -it cicd -- bash -c "cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo"`

Answer (score 9):

This is how you can complete your desired commands:

```
kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -c <CONTAINER_NAME> -- /bin/bash
cat /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && echo
```

NOTE: if you only have 1 container in your pod, you can omit `-c <CONTAINER_NAME>`

`-it` is short for `stdin` and `tty` -> this is your [COMMAND]

`/bin/bash` is an argument here, you can pass more than one

`--` separates the arguments you want to pass

After the first command is ran, you're inside a bash shell and can run whatever other commands inside the container.